# How to play Sound of a Destroyed Object

Tags: unity

So I have implemented grenades, and thats working fine. Now I want some explosion sound, but the problem is that the sound is still playing when the grenade is explode and I Destroy the grenade. Does someone have an idea how to circumvent this? I mean I could disable all Components on the nade so that it's invisible etc. and destroy it after the sound is done playing, but I feel like that's a bit weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Disable the render component, and delay the destruction of the grenade until the sound/(particle/visual effect?) are done. Destroy takes an optional parameter for a time delay: [`GameObject.Destroy(yourGrenadeObject, timeToWaitToDestroy);`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)
2. You can create a new object in place of the grenade that plays the sound, does the visual effect, does collision checks for damage, etc. This explosion object would destroy itself when the sound or effects have come to an end.

Personally, I'd likely go with the second option as the explosion object could be used in other situations than just grenades, so you're saving yourself some work. I should say, on the topic of destroying game objects like this, it's probably best to be using some kind of object pool to re-use these game objects. That means disabling them after they're done and re-enabling them when they're to be used again. This saves on allocating and garbage clean-up of memory.